# Garbage chars at the beginning of file

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm reading a file, character by character using:

```
while(1)
{
    char c ='\0';
    c = infile.get();
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

but I have a specific file where this code reads 3 (garbage = strange) characters before the actual data in my file (and only on the beginning of the file).

I've tried to open this file with some text editors (notepad and notepad++) but it seems right = no strange characters before my data...

Any idea why this strange chars are being read and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Probably a UTF-8 [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: That's probably the Byte Order Marc that indicates the encoding of a UNICODE file. OTOH, don't do this `char c ='\0'; c = infile.get();` as it's enough to say `char c = infile.get();`.

Comment: Why are you assigning `'\0'` to `c` before re-assigning it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see this all the time, people coming from certain other languages believe all variables have to have constant initializations at definition time...

Comment: Try use a hex editor to check the *real* data of the file and you'll see what the 'strange' characters are.

Comment: @Marius Bancila, just tried to use a Hex Editor and it starts with 0x30 = 0, which is my data...

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, I was just doing it as a last resort for my problem, REALLY getting sure my variable was changing the value.

Comment: I was checking the wrong file... it really is Byte Order Mark with the hexadecimal representation of `EF BB BF` or `ï»¿`.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *Byte Order Mark* sequence with the hexadecimal representation of `EF BB BF` or `ï»¿`.

more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).